# Extract variables and their values from a cell with comma-delimited data

Tags: matlab

I have a plot data generated by a program and it produces a csv file in the format shown in the attached image (imported into a cell to workspace)
[image]

As you can see the first row contains all the variable names and the following rows have their values, all being comma-delimited.

Now, what I'm doing is as shown below:

```
name_vars = strsplit(data_csv{1},',');
values = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,data_csv(2:end),'Uni',false));
```

I'm thinking somehow to combine the name_vars and values into one package.  I tried the struct, but not quite.  That's, however, the next problem to solve.

The first problem I need to solve is that the operations above take about a minute with the amount of data being operated on and it's not acceptable.  I'm looking for a much more efficient way of extracting variables from this cell.

If someone can also teach me to resolve another issue, that will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've become a fan of the `table` type for keeping track of tabular data.

t = readtable(filename);

Comment: the readtable seems to be the fastest.  I've been searching, but couldn't find if it's possible to import csv file starting from a specific row. I can specify a range, but I don't know the number of variables (# of columns) and the size of the data (# of rows), but I know there will be four lines of header that mess up the readtable.  I have to delete those four lines. Once I have a complete table, I need to save individual variables into a *.mat file.  I'm thinking to use "table2strcut" and "save -struct".  I'm wondering if there's a way to use writetable command to do the same.

Comment: Yeah... I often delete headers manually or have a bash script that makes a copy for importing to Matlab. I try to have clean files for MATLAB to read (even go so far as to have Java programs redo a csv). In my experience, the MATLAB text io tools aren't great for handling more complicated situations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `csvread` or `dlmread` should provide superior results.

For example:

```
values  = csvread(filename,1,0);
```